# Как запаковать Python-скрипт в исполняемый файл чтобы запускать без предустановки интерпретатора?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, binary-file, executable

Использую: Python3.8 и Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS; Версия GNOME: 3.36.3

Мне необходимо создать Python-скрипт, который запускается из графической среды Ubuntu с рабочего стола. Скрипт должен открывать терминал, запрашивать ввод с клавиатуры, выводит в терминал отчёты и прочее что в нём прописано.
Скрипт я создал. Через терминал он запускается и отрабатывает правильно. Так же мне, с горем пополам, удалось запаковать его в исполняемый файл с помощью pyinstaller'а. Однако данный файл всё равно запускается из предварительно открытого терминала, а мне нужно чтобы я мог запускать его из графической среды по двойному клику мышки.
Подскажите что нужно сделать, чтобы добиться такого результата? Или как вызвать терминал ubuntu из самого скрипта перед выполнением основного кода?

Comment: [terminal=true](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries_%28Русский%29)?

Comment: Достаточно дать разрешение на выполнение скрипта и прописать шибанг в самом скрипте

Comment: Это всё конечно ооочень здорово, но не могли бы вы по человечески написать как это сделать? То, о чём вы говорите я уже выполнил, но толку нет. Видимо я что-то делаю неправильно, поэтому прошу напишите как этого сделать.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Answer (score 2):

Напишите [шебанг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix)) в первой строке и дать разрешение на выполнение скрипта:

```
$ cat <<eof > yourscript
#!/usr/bin/env python
print(input("hello from python: "))
eof

$ chmod +x yourscript

$ ./yourscript
hello from python
```

Сохраните на рабочем столе новый файл yourscript.desktop, поместите туда следующие строчки, и не забудте сделайть его выполняемым:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=yourscript
Exec=yourscript
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

Comment: вопрос был о запуске терминала. как это сделать, я подсказал ещё в первом комментарии к вопросу.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Но автор вопроса же написал позже, что это ему не помогло, вот я и подумал, а что еще не хватает. Ны хорошо, дополнил.